# validation using c# for name, email and dropdown fields-Webform

Tags: c#, validation

I have created a webform using asp.net c#. 
I know how to apply validation using regular expression but need to validate fields using c#. Please help anyone help validating field using c#

Comment: Do you have some code to show where you're stuck?

Comment: @PJvG I don't have any code

Comment: Well then, could you try to write some code, or maybe some pseudocode, to better explain what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: sorry I have just started coding, I want to apply validation on name field conditions like, 1. the field should not be blank 2. it should accept only characters. Is this mus info enough?

Comment: I've provided an answer now, but perhaps it might also be useful for you to find some programming tutorials online about asp.net and c# to learn more about them.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a special class to indicate a value (e.g. a name) is validated might be a solution to your problem.

An example:

```
public class ValidatedName
{
    // private constructor, called only by Validate method
    private ValidatedName(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    // read-only property Name
    public string Name { get; }

    // method to validate the name, returns null if name is not valid,
    // alternatively you could change this to throw an exception if name is not valid.
    public static ValidatedName? Validate(string name)
    {
        // validate name here, for example name may not be empty
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            return null;
        }

        // name is not empty so return new ValidatedName object containing name
        return new ValidatedName(name);
    }
}
```

Everywhere you need a validated name, you should use this class then instead of `string name`. This class can be used as followed:

```
var validatedName = ValidatedName.Validate(name);
if (validatedName != null)
{
    // name is not null and thus valid
    // do stuff with valid name here
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can validate the name in the method where you actually need a validated name, for example:

```
public void SomeMethod(string name)
{
    // validate name here, for example name may not be empty
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    {
        return; // stop executing method because name is not valid
    }

    // do stuff for which a valid name is needed
    // ...
}
```

I hope this points you in the right direction. Try some different implementations, pick one you like, and please come back if you run into any problems and can't get to a solution by doing your own research.

Answer (score -1):

if you're using visual studio 2015 just go to the asp tag and for buttons write onClick="" then click Ctrl+Space it will appear create new event, for dropdown list it is selectedIndexChanged="", and for check box and radio buttons onCheckedChanged=""

Comment: Whilst this is useful for anyone new to visual studio, it does not directly address the original post. Please include logic for actually validating the field values or you haven't really answered the question at all.